# Commenting html/django template lines in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: html, django, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I write a Django website in Visual Studio - but often instead of
 `{# comment #}` style I would prefer `<!-- comment -->`. Problem is, Visual Studio doesn't allow me just to change commenting style. For example, after commenting (`Ctrl + K + C`) I have this:

```
    {#<style>
        body { height: 100%; }
        html { height: 100%; }
    </style>#}
```

and I want to have this:

```
<!--
<style>
    body { height: 100%; }
    html { height: 100%; }
</style>
-->
```

That's really frustrating for me - could I get from you any tips how to change it?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a plugin available for VS that will solve that however, I don't think it natively supports block vs. line comments. In Visual Studio Code, however, on the Edit menu there are separate options for block and line comments which sometimes behave differently, if you're willing to edit in VS Code.